# Gaming preference (CPU VS GPU)

Tags: gpu, cpu-usage

I have a pc with nvidia gt520 2 gb ddr2 graphics card and a Intel core 2 duo processor with 6 gb ram 
While playing assassin creed syndicate
In graphics setting it only need 1850 mb of VRAM although it is very lagging. does it is due to CPU?
I want to know that how high end game use CPU vs GPU

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions only, so unfortunately this question is off-topic here. See the [tour] and [help/on-topic] for more information.

Comment: OK thanks for giving information